# Grails project does not resolve dependencies during runtime from libraries inside its own lib directory

Tags: grails, ivy, dependency-management

Ladies and Gents,

I have a very simple grails app from which I need to invoke our company's platform API via straight class dependency API call.

I have a pending question [here on Stack](http://goo.gl/UCJ1o). It relates to dependency management on Grails project. While I could not get that problem resolved, I dumped our internal artifacts into lib directory of grails project. Our artifacts have Ivy dependencies files built into them, so I only specified "root" jars hoping that Grails dependency management will resolve the rest using transitive dependencies. I specified "runtime" for dependencies.

The application seem to resolve dependencies just fine but to a point. For instance,
it resolves classes A, B, C, D, etc. in jar A. It resolves class A in jar B, but not class B in jar B. Class B is referenced inside class A, but I get a "ClassNotFoundException" message for class B.

Question:
What am I doing wrong as to specifying dependencies for the project? Why does Grails runtime fund class A in jar B but not class B? I can easily look class B in eclipse and it finds it in exactly the same jar as class A. What gives?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you drop a new jar into `lib` you have to do

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

to make Grails see it.

Comment: You may also have to run 'grails clean'.